# É possível gerar arquivo de logs de um arquivo Python que foi transformado em executável?

Tags: python, arquivo, log, .exe

Olá, eu crie o executável do código Python abaixo com o módulo `pyinstaller`.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import webbrowser
import re
import popular4
import logging
from datetime import datetime
agora = datetime.now()
logging.basicConfig(filename='example2.log', filemode='w', 
level=logging.DEBUG)
while True: 
    tabela    = popular4.Banco()
    if (tabela.PegaEmailDigitado() != tuple()): 
        nome        = tabela.PegaEmailDigitado()[0][0]
        email       = tabela.PegaEmailDigitado()[0][1]
        senha       = tabela.PegaEmailDigitado()[0][2]
        data1       = tabela.PegaEmailDigitado()[0][3]
        matricula   = tabela.PegaEmailDigitado()[0][4]
        rg          = tabela.PegaEmailDigitado()[0][5]
        if (len(email) > 1):
            url = "https://aluno.unb.br/alunoweb/default/sca/solicitarsenha"
            data = urllib.urlencode({'nome': nome, 'matricula': matricula, 
            'identidade': rg,'data_nascimento': data1})
            results = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
            conteudo_html = str(results.read())
            email_alter = matricula + "@aluno.unb.br"
            if (tabela.is_EmailDuplicado(email)):
                tabela.Inserir(nome, email, senha, data1, matricula, rg, 2)
                tabela.ApagaTabela_transitoria()
                logging.debug("\nHorario do log: %s, nome: %s, email: %s, 
                data: %s, senha: %s, matricula: %s, rg: %s. E-mail já 
                existe, não autenticado.\n"%(agora, nome, email, data1, 
                senha, matricula, rg ))
                continue
        elif (email_alter in conteudo_html ):
            print ("Consegui!")
            tabela.Inserir(nome, email, senha, data1, matricula, rg, 1)
            tabela.ApagaTabela_transitoria()
            logging.debug("\nHorario do log: %s, nome: %s, email: %s, data: 
            %s, senha: %s, matricula: %s, rg: %s, autenticado: Sim \n"%
            (agora, nome, email, data1, senha, matricula, rg ))
        else:
            tabela.Inserir(nome, email, senha, data1, matricula, rg, 0)
            tabela.ApagaTabela_transitoria()
            logging.debug("\nHorario do log: %s, nome: %s, email: %s, data: 
            %s, senha: %s, matricula: %s, rg: %s, autenticado: Não \n"%
            (agora, nome, email, data1, senha, matricula, rg ))
    else:
        logging.debug("\nHorario do log: %s, nome: %s, email: %s, data: %s, 
        senha: %s, matricula: %s, rg: %s, Email Inválido, não autenticado! 
        \n"%(agora, nome, email, data1, senha, matricula, rg ))
        tabela.ApagaTabela_transitoria()
print "Esperando Mudança no Banco..."
```

Quando eu rodo o código com a extensão .py `python nome_do_arquivo.py` ele gera o arquivo de log chamado example2.log. Porém quando eu faço o executável do msm arquivo e coloco ele pra rodar ele não gera nenhum arquivo. É possível que fazer isso?

Comment: Não seria problema de permissão de escrita? Já tentou executar como administrador?

Comment: O executável tá rodando -em segundo plano- como root, ele faz outros comandos como mudanças no Banco de Dados. Porém, ele não gera o arquivo de logs.

Comment: Já consultou o ["Quando as coisas dão errado"](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html), no manual do pyinstaler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu adicionei a linha de código abaixo para resolver o problema

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
```